# しばらく放置しているとVcXsrvで表示しているWSL2のubuntuの画面が操作出来なくなる。

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wsl-2

rubyでの開発の為、linux環境が必要となりwindows11にてWSL2で
ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
xfce4
で構築した環境を
VcXsrv (xfce4-sessionコマンド)
で表示させて使用しています。

しかし、調べもの等でhost側をしばらく操作(WSL2を放置)した後にWSL2に戻ると画面上でマウスやキーボードの操作が効かなくなっていることが多々あります。
ただ、画面がフリーズしているという訳でもなく(テキスト入力時のカーソルの点滅等はしている)、操作が一切行えない状態となります。
この状態になった際でもコマンドプロンプトのコンソール上には特にエラーやメッセージが追加されていることはありません。
仮想環境周りの知識が疎く、何故しばらく放置すると操作を受け付けなくなるのか自分が調べた範囲ではヒントになるような情報も得られず、何卒ご教授頂ければ幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

下記、操作を受け付けなくなった後にwslに対してps n -efHを打った実行結果
↓

[image: 実行結果1]

[image: 実行結果2]

Comment: エラー表示は全く無しということですか？この現象が起こる時はWindows側はCPUがフル活動状態になってたりしますか？次に操作不可になった時、PowerShellまたはCMDにて`wsl ~`をもう一度実行してみて下さい。正常に起動する場合はこの質問に`ps n -efH`の実行結果を足して下さい。

Comment: >Gui Imamuraさん 
コメントありがとうございます。
再度発生しましたのでps n -efH実行結果の先頭と最後のスクショを貼りました。
(xfce4-sessionコマンドを打っているコマンドプロンプトはxfce4起動でビジー状態の為、新しく立ち上げたコマンドプロンプトで実行しました。)
CPUの状態はfullではありませんでした。
ご確認よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 操作不可になっても`wsl --shutdown`で正常に終了させることはできますか？色々聞いてまだ解決に至らなくてすみません。

Comment: >Gui Imamuraさん コメントありがとうございます。とんでもないです。自分では解法に至らないので相談にのっていただけるのは助かります。 wsl --shutdownでwslを終了させることは可能です。